# Adding PHP extension to IIS Without Restarting

Tags: php, sql-server, iis

I have a working PHP website at a client where I work which runs on IIS. As we are switching to MsSQL, I need to enable the php_pdo_sqlsrv_53_nts.dll. However once I'm enabling the extension, I start to receive a 500 error. My guess is that I need to restart the webserver but for certain reasons at this time we would like to avoid it.

Can you please tell me whether a restart of the web server is necessary on IIS to enable correctly a php dll?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes - see [Microsoft.com](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296203%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Mind you, restarting any of my webserver takes only a few seconds so I'm not sure if that's a big issue for your client. Does he have more than one server with a load balancer or something? In that case you can do them one by one or something? Or maybe there's another smart idea of temporarily rerouting traffic elsewhere through changing the DNS?

Answer (score 1):

A restart is **required** even if you work on your localhost !

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to popular opinion, I'm going to say **No**, and here's why:

Since you are using IIS, you could try recycling the App Pool, if the restart is not necessarily urgent.

It might take a little while to cycle, but "recycle" uses an overlapping method, keeping the old process up until its active requests are finished while a new process handles any newly generated requests. This continues until all existing processes are finished, then the old pool gracefully exits. This will ensure that service is not disrupted for the end users. On the down side, if you have users that sit on the site for long periods of time, it may take a while before your PHP extension becomes available.

I've had success with this method in the past, was able to install PHP extensions without restarting IIS outright.

To Recycle in IIS 7:

1. Open Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager
2. Navigate to SERVERNAME > Application Pools
3. Select the pool you wish to recycle (the one attached to the site where you need the extension)
4. In the Action pane, click "Recycle..."